# Spring hibernate does not find column of onetomany relationship

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

So here is an example close to my actual code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Products")
@Data
public class Product{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="productno")
    private long ID;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String productName;

    private ProductCategory category;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Category")
@Data
public class ProductCategory{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="categoryno")
    private long ID;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String categoryName;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="category")
    private List<Product> product;
}
```

aswell as a thymeleaf template, that displays a bunch of those in a table using th:each

and a controller that sends the data to those templates. Those templates have been tested and they should work.

the problem is, when `bootRun`ning and opening the page, i get a error:

`SQL.SyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'product0_.productCategory_category'`

Looking at this error, it seems it tried to read the join column name as `productCategory_category` instead of just `category` (which is the desired one)

Answer (score 0):

`@JoinColumn` needs to go on Product class on `ProductCategory` field and `name="categoryno"`

Comment: when doing this, `@JoinColumn(name="categoryno") private ProductCategory category` i suddenly get an error like this: `Table 'MySchema.ProductCategory_product' doesn't exist`

Answer (score 0):

So i've solved this thing with

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Products")
@Data
public class Product{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="productno")
    private long ID;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String productName;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="category", referencedColumnName="categoryno")
    private ProductCategory category;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Category")
@Data
public class ProductCategory{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="categoryno")
    private long ID;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String categoryName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="category")
    private List<Product> product;
}
```

i have no idea why this works, but hey: magic